# Mule - JUnit FunctionalTestCase getConfigResources(), what return statement should I use?

Tags: mule

From Mule in Action Second Edition eBook, I'm seeing the following code snippet from Chapter 1

```
public class ProductRegistrationFunctionalTestCase extends FunctionalTestCase {
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "./src/main/app/product_registration.xml";
    } ...
```

and, am seeing the below from Chapter 12

```
 public class TransformingBridgeTestCase extends FunctionalTestCase {
    protected String getConfigResources()
    {
       return "functional-test-connectors.xml,jms-transforming-bridge.xml";
    }...
```

I have two questions regarding getConfigResources() return statement.

(1) Why is ./src/main/... not required from the example in Chapter 12?

(2) How does it work behind the scene by having two xml in the return statement from Chapter 12 example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getConfigResources() should return a comma separated list of resources that can be loaded from the classpath. The return value is parsed by the ConfigurationBuilder attached to the FunctionalTestCase, and a MuleContext is instantiated using the resources. You would need to use the full src/main... path from application root folder if you do not have the app folder in your classpath.

Comment: "You would need to use the full src/main... path from application root folder if you do not have the app folder in your classpath." How do I place the app folder in my classpath?